# Does TeXmaker have the ability to make custom user commands?

Tags: texmaker

I'm wondering if Texmaker (by far my favorite text editor for LaTeX) has the ability to make custom user commands. For example, I want a quicker way to bold my math fonts rather than having to type `\bm{}` every time (among a plethura of other quick commands I would like to have). Is there an easy way to do this?

I do see that there is a "user commands" options in the texmaker menu. Is this where I would do it, and if so how do I make my own commands? I can't seem to figure it out...Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for a way to define new commands in LaTeX or for a way to let TeXmaker offer shortcuts for your custom commands?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Default shortcuts can be edited in `Options -> Configure Texmaker -> Shortcuts`.

Texmaker also allows custom snippets of text to be inserted in the document with shortcuts, this functionality is known as *User Tags* in the User menu.

Goto `User -> User Tags -> Edit User Tags` and define a tag with the content you wish:

```
\thisIsCool{@}
```

Now press `Shift + F1...F10` to get the snippet pasted in the current cursor position. The `@` character is a jump marker and your cursor will end up at the first marker encountered.

For more information: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION33

Comment: Good, the `@` will also be replaced by the current selection during editing.

Comment: Interestingly, there are two kinds of user tags, the other kind can be accessed from the Structure tab -> User (a button on the left bar). Then right-click -> Add tag. These tags can be expanded by writing `:<tag-trigger>` and pressing right arrow key.