# Save default file content in texmaker

Tags: texmaker

I have been fiddling with texmaker for the last day. I am getting the hang of it, but writing the basic structure of a document is tedious and requires me to constantly look at the cheat sheet, so I want to save a document to be used as default.

My idea is to write the basic structure of most of the documents I will be doing and then make texmaker paste everything in that document in every new .tex file I create (Unless I specify otherwise). Is this possible? How can it be done?

I've searched extensively but I haven't found any way of doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three choices:

## User Tags

```
User menu/User Tags/Edit User Tags
```

There you have 10 slots which you can name, and to each one of them belongs a piece of text. You can edit that text to contain the contents you copy and paste usually. The next time you need them, click

```
User menu/User Tags/
```

and then select the one you need.

## Wizard

The Quick Start Wizard in the Wizards menu bootstraps a document in a few clicks.

## Template file

```
File/New by copying an existing file
```

This option opens a new document and copies the contents of an existing one into it. It remembers what document you last chose as the template, and opens up at the same folder next time.

Comment: Yes! That last option is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much :)

Comment: For more info on `User Tags`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136333/does-texmaker-have-the-ability-to-make-custom-user-commands/136344#136344