# Macro/shortcut for defining text portion as code

Tags: macros, verbatim, code

I'm currently converting my thesis into LaTeX, and i have an issue: being an IT thesis, I have tons of code quotes.

The problem is not about the blocks of code: they are not that many and i can wrap them with {verbatim} tags. The problem is about the millions of inline single terms which should be formatted the same way.

Is there a way, for example, to define a macro or shortcut or whatever which, is i select one word and click it, automatically wraps it with {verbatim} (or equivalent) tags?

Hope I've been clear. This could really spare me hours of tedious work, thank You in advance!

Comment: \newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

Comment: this is the job of (la)TeX editor, so what is your's?

Comment: Do you mean auto-conversion: when you type ***, the editor automatically changes it into `\texttt{***}`? If so, I suppose that is not what this site handles, and if not, you should define a macro Andrew shows.

Comment: An example of what I mean: i have this phrase "We inserted this <tag> into the code." What I would like to do is just selecting "<tag>" and pressing e.g. ctrl+something to wrap it, without writing myself anything.

Comment: To be more clear: writing \vrb instead of \begin{verbatim} is not a big advantage for me, I'd need to assign that to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You need to tell us what editor you are using as every one of them is different.

Comment: You're right, i forgot it. I am currently using Gummi, but I could change it if it's not good for this purpouse. I'm on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: Of course, you have already considered (and deemed inadequate for your needs) using the _listings_ package, which, among many other features, also provides the `\lstMakeShortInline` command…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I moved to TexMaker editor and found what I was looking for. Thanks to everyone who got interested in this question.

If you have the same issue and are looking for an answer, [here it is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136333/does-texmaker-have-the-ability-to-make-custom-user-commands) (for TexMaker users).