# How do I add shortcuts to TeX Maker?

Tags: tex-core, texmaker, shortcut

For example, I want to create a shortcut for `\(...\)` command and or more specific one `_{\circ}`    etc. Because it is hard to write in a minute. But I cannot create a new shortcut. I only configure the shortcuts that already exist. Is there way to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136333/does-texmaker-have-the-ability-to-make-custom-user-commands) may be of help. If you want greater customisation options, you may prefer TeXstudio, an offshoot of  Texmaker.