# Custom keyboard shortcuts in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker

I find myself typing out

```
\begin{gather*}
     text here, started by tab
\end{gather*}
```

way more than i should be. I want to set a shortcut, namely ctrl+g, that would insert this text, and also place my cursor where 'text here ... ' starts, and haven't found a way to do this in TexMaker. Is such a thing possible? If not the cursor bit, at least the text.

Comment: This question was answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136333/does-texmaker-have-the-ability-to-make-custom-user-commands).